# Identify JSON and HTML request with Play Framework

Tags: html, json, playframework, request, content-type

I want to know if there exists any way to identify with the Play Framework (with Java language not Scala) if the request is coming from JSON or HTML.

I find a method that is:

```
If (request().accepts(MimeType.HTML)){
    //code 
} else{
    //code
}
```

The only way that this works is that the JSON only accepts `application/json` if not will accept first if clause.

Want I want is that Play identify the `Content-Type` and not the `Accept` header.

Comment: `if ( "application/json".equals(request().getHeader("Content-Type")) ){}`?

Comment: @Salem write an answer instead of comment, especially if it's valid

Comment: Hi Salem for your answer, but i am getting[ NullPointerException: null]
when i am sending a GET request with my browser (CHROME)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the request body is parsable JSON without looking at the header manually.

```
public static Result someApi() {
    // Check if the body is parsable json
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null) {
        // The request didn't have a json body
        return ok("not json");
    }

    // Do something with the json
    return ok("got json");
}
```

Comment: But in that case the html request will return got json i think.

Comment: It will return "got json" when json is used. Otherwise it will return "not json".

Comment: This is not true if a request does not have the correct mime type. At least it is not the case if the mime-type header is "Content-Type: application/csp-report". The body is json, still it's not parsed.